# Does Nginx need to have access to php files

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

If using nginx + php-fpm, does nginx need to have access to the php files?

Context: building a kuberentes pod, with two containers: nginx and php-fpm, we can built the php code into php-fpm container. It's possible to share the php files with volumes, but is it really needed?

Please correct my understanding: nginx will just forward a pre-processed request to php-fpm (using fast-cgi protocol) which will execute the script. So php-fpm needs to read php files. However I don't see the reason why would nginx need to, apart from checking if script is found or not. It could send the script name to php-fpm without accessing the php file.

Thanks

Comment: Did anyone have setup this scenario (nginx and php-fpm+code separate containers) successfully?

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't need access to the files unless you use `try_files`. You can safely use a remote socket as upstream without needing to populate the files on the nginx container. php-fpm uses the fcgi protocol which passes the path of the file to process as the SCRIPT_NAME and SCRIPT_FILENAME fcgi parameters.

Answer (score 4):

In the standard `nginx` and `php-fpm` design `try_files` checks for the existence of a file and then sends the file path to `php-fpm` over a TCP/IP or unix socket for execution so `nginx` needs to be able to see the file - `nginx` is the file server whether the file is a static html file or a script, and `php-fpm` is the processor in this case.

Comment: So nginx needs access to find the file, but it doesn't need to be able to read it.

Comment: The nginx user would need the read right to be able to pass the file if that's what you mean.

Comment: nginx does not send the file (as in contents) over a socket to PHP-FPM. It merely sends the path+filename.

Comment: Corrected, but doesn't that mean you can't have nginx and PHP-FPM in separate pods as the questioner is conceiving without having the PHP files mounted in the same location?

Comment: @SimonGreenwood no. It only needs to KNOW the path that is valid for fpm. You can absolutely do `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/index.php;`, even if that path does not exist in nginx's pod.